# How to run the latest Memgraph Plarform using Docker?

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I use the command `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform` to run Memgraph Platform.

I can see that Memgraph Platform 2.10 is out https://hub.docker.com/r/memgraph/memgraph-platform/tags but this Docker command is not pulling it. I have to use

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.10.0-memgraph2.10.0-lab2.8.0-mage1.9
```

Can I use some shorter tag than the one `memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.10.0-memgraph2.10.0-lab2.8.0-mage1.9` to run Memgraph Platform 2.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue a `docker run` command, the Docker daemon first looks into the local image registry on the host machine. Utilizing the local cache, the daemon searches for the specified image tag, such as `latest`. If the tag is found within the local registry, the search is satisfied, and the corresponding image is used to instantiate a container.

If the specified tag is not in the local registry, the daemon will extend search to remote repositories, like Docker Hub.

You can inspect the images and tags currently available on your local machine, you can use the docker images command:

```
docker images
```

This command will provide a list of all images along with their tags, image IDs, creation dates, and sizes stored locally.

If you want to ensure that you have the latest version of the Memgraph Platform image before running a container, you can use the `docker pull`. First run `docker pull memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest` and then `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest`.